# How to put references into the same style as the rest of the text

Tags: hyperref

I put my subsections in `\textbf{}` and my subsubsections into `\textit{}` The same style I gave the corresponding numbers in the Table of contents.
Referencing to these subsections I get the same style in the reference Number, but I need them to be exactly like the rest of the text.
Thanks for any help!!

This would be my MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt, fleqn, pdftex, version=last, x11names,pointlessnmbers]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[]{ngerman, geometry, graphicx, keyval, ifpdf, ifvtex, placeins, nicefrac, abstract}  
\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{tocloft}  
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}   
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}  
\usepackage{ae, sectsty}  
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{2em}  
\setlength{\cftparanumwidth}{3em}  
\setlength{\cftsubparanumwidth}{4em}  
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2.5em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{4.5em}  
\setlength{\cftparaindent}{6.5em}  
\setlength{\cftsubparaindent}{9.5em}  

\makeatletter  
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{6}{13.5em}{5em}}  

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}  
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\textbf{\arabic{subsection}}}  
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\itshape\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}  
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}}  
\renewcommand \thesubparagraph {\small\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{subparagraph}}  

\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection.}   
\renewcommand\p@subsubsection{\thesection.}   
\renewcommand\p@paragraph{\thesection.}   

\makeatother  


\begin{document}  
\phantomsection  
\tableofcontents  

\section{First Section}\label{sec:FS}  

\subsection{\textbf{First Subsection}}\label{subsec:FS}  
\ref{sec:FS}  
\subsubsection{\textit{First Subsubsection}}\label{subsubsec:FS}  
\ref{subsec:FS}  
\subsubsection{\textit{Second Subsubsection}}\label{subsubsec:SS}  
\ref{subsubsec:FS}  
\subsection{\textbf{Second Subsection}}\label{subsec:SS}  

\section{Second Section}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By default latex will do as you say you wish, so you have some code stopping that. Please _always_ include a small complete document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never put formatting instruction in `\thesection` and the like commands. Removing the inessential parts of your example, here is what seems to be what you want.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt, fleqn, version=last]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}  
\usepackage{tocloft}  

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}  
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.5em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{3em}  
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2.5em}  
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{4.5em}  

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\bfseries\itshape}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\itshape}

\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents  

\section{First Section}\label{sec:FS}

\subsection{First Subsection}\label{subsec:FS}
\ref{sec:FS}

\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}\label{subsubsec:FS}  
\ref{subsec:FS}

\subsubsection{Second Subsubsection}\label{subsubsec:SS}  
\ref{subsubsec:FS}

\subsection{Second Subsection}\label{subsec:SS}  

\section{Second Section}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Section numbers in titles will use the same font for the title proper, so you don't need to add formatting for them.

---

Some notes. The `ae` package is obsolete; `ngerman` should be substituted with a call to `babel`. I added also `inputenc` for inputting directly accented characters, adjust the option to the actual encoding of your document.